# Create timestamp from Date and Hour columns - Pyspark3

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, etl, amazon-emr

I have a pyspark dataframe that contains two columns that I would like to create a timestamp from.

```
+----------+------------+
|start_date|daypart_hour|
+----------+------------+
|2019-09-17|          22|
|2019-09-17|          11|
|2019-09-17|           9|
+----------+------------+
```

daypart_hour is a scale from midnight to midnight that goes 0-23. 0 associated with midnight and 23 associated with 11pm.

I'm curious how to make this... Or something like it.

```
+----------+------------+---------------------+
|start_date|daypart_hour|          start_dt_ts|
+----------+------------+---------------------+
|2019-09-17|          22|2019-09-17 10:00:00pm|
|2019-09-17|          11|2019-09-17 11:00:00am|
|2019-09-17|           9|2019-09-17 09:00:00am|
+----------+------------+---------------------+
```

There are always 0-23 hours for each date. There are no missing values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **`date_format`**, **`to_timestamp`**, and **`concat`** to get desired result. Refer to [Java Simple Date format](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for more info on datetime chars.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df.withColumn("start_dt_ts", \
              F.date_format(F.to_timestamp(F.concat("start_date","daypart_hour"),"yyyy-MM-ddHH"),\
                                          "yyyy-MM-dd hh:ss:SSa")).show(truncate=False)

#+----------+------------+---------------------+
#|start_date|daypart_hour|start_dt_ts          |
#+----------+------------+---------------------+
#|2019-09-17|22          |2019-09-17 10:00:00PM|
#|2019-09-17|11          |2019-09-17 11:00:00AM|
#|2019-09-17|9           |2019-09-17 09:00:00AM|
#+----------+------------+---------------------+
```

Comment: this solution did not work for me